# matlab KeyPressFcn for holding a key

Tags: matlab

I would like to allow the user to zoom only while the control key is held (depressed). I have implemented this as follows within a `WindowKeyPressFcn` callback function:

```
function keypress_callback(obj, evd, hZoom)
switch evd.Key
  case 'control'
    set(hZoom,'Enable','on');
end
%disp(evd); % used for debugging purposes
```

This function accepts a zoom object handle (`hZoom`) that is passed from the main program at the moment the callback function is activated (`set(hFigure,'WindowKeyPressFcn',{@keypress_callback,hZoom});`). I have written a similar `WindowKeyReleaseFcn` (set via `set(hFigure,'WindowKeyReleaseFcn',{@keyrelease_callback,hZoom});`) to disable zooming when control is released.

```
function keyrelease_callback(obj, evd, hZoom)
switch evd.Key
  case 'control'
    set(hZoom,'Enable','off');
end
%disp(evd); % used for debugging purposes
```

The goal is to allow normal zooming behavior (click to zoom in by a factor; shift-click to zoom out by a factor; drag clicking to zoom in on a selected region) only while the `Ctrl` key is depressed. As soon as this modifier key is released, zooming ability should be disabled.

However, this behavior does not work as intended. Simply testing (by `disp(evd)`) whether a key is pressed reveals that any number of key presses can be made with arbitrary keys; however, if the pressed key is `Ctrl`, only one such press can be made, and all subsequent presses of `Ctrl` are ignored, while all subsequent presses of any other key cause the key to appear in the Matab command window instead of triggering the `keypress_callback` function. Thus, pressing `Ctrl` appears to somehow inactivate the `keypress_callback` function, perhaps because focus is shifted from the figure to the zoom object? As a corollary question, the `WindowKeyReleaseFcn` seems to work fine for non-modifier keys (the `evd` shows the correct released key), but the `key` in `evd` is empty if the released key is a non-modifier key.

I would be grateful if someone could demonstrate the correct implementation of the control-dependent zoom behavior as envisaged.

Answer (score 1):

The more modern way to do things seems to be:

```
gca
zoom on
z = zoom(gcf);
set(z, 'ButtonDownFilter', @ZoomGate)
```

where `ZoomGate.m` contains something like:

```
function inhibitZoom = ZoomGate(varargin)

if ismember('control', get(gcbo,'currentModifier'))
    inhibitZoom = 0;
else
    inhibitZoom = 1;
end
```

EDIT in response to questioner's comments:

My first suggestion was to use a `WindowButtonDownFcn` callback which then calls `zoom` itself if it detects the control modifier. This is fine provided you have control over the `zoom` implementation. Looking back at my code (I did something like this anything up to 15 years ago) I find that it used to be simple — `zoom` was an m-file and had an obvious way of calling it: `zoom down` meant "the button has just been pressed".  Then, in that way that they do, MathWorks moved the goal posts and changed `zoom`. It looks like my response at the time was to re-implement my own `zoom` in the older, simpler style. Doesn't help you, unless you actually want that code (let me know).

Comment: On my Linux system, pressing control also leads to `alt` being returned by `gcbo` (shift becomes `extend` and alt becomes nothing). If one clicks the mouse rapidly, then regardless of what key is held (or if no keys are held), the value returned by `gcbo` is `open`. Do you know what this means?

Comment: Before I started trying to implement said behavior using `WindowKeyPressFcn` & `WindowKeyReleaseFcn`, I was trying an implementation using `WindowButtonDownFcn`, as you have suggested. To obtain the depressed control key, I was using `modifiers = get(obj,'currentModifier'); ctrlIsPressed = ismember('control',modifiers);` Do you know whether this approach (`get(obj,'currentModifier')`) is equivalent to your approach (`get(gcbo,'SelectionType'`)?

Comment: The behavior after adopting the `gcbo` approach is as follows: the initial ctrl+click activates the `zoom` object (via `set(hZoom,'Enable','on')`) but the click itself is discarded (so no zoom actually takes place). Subsequently clicking zooms as normally, but the zoom can never be disabled (despite including `set(hZoom,'Enable','off')` in the `else` statement of the `gbco`/`alt` comparison statement. The zoom object remains activated throughout the duration of the script.

Comment: I have changed my answer.  To respond to your questions in the comments:  (1) Yes, for detecting the control modifier `ismember('control', get(gcbo, 'CurrentModifier'))` is probably cleaner and more robust than using `isequal(get(gcbo, 'SelectionType'), 'alt')`. Again this was a legacy code issue.  (2) Yes, SelectionType `'open'` refers to a double-click.  Like, you know, you double-click to "open" something.  I know. But there's logic everywhere if you squint hard enough.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I can't get the example code to work. In line with [zoom help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html), I tried variations like enclosing the return value in square brackets in the function definition (i.e., `[inhibitZoom]`) and using logical boolean expressions or strings like `true`, `false`, `'true'`, and `'false'` instead of `0` and `1`, but none of these variations results in control-dependent zooming. Indeed the `ButtonDownFilter` function doesn't even seem to be accessed (I've placed simple `disp` commands within to alert if it is called).

Comment: Did you start from scratch? (paste `close all, axes, zoom on, set(zoom(gcf), 'ButtonDownFilter', @ZoomGate)` )  This works for me (with the function returning numeric 0 or 1) if pasted into Matlab R2013a for OSX. `disp` shows that the function is always called. (NB: on the mac ctrl-click may also be interpreted as right-click, so there's the added side effect of popping up a contextual menu full of zoom options, but it still behaves as intended once you click again outside the popup: if the original click was with the desired modifiers, it zooms; if not, no popup appears in the first place).

Comment: Still doesn't work. Must be a version issue. I'm running R2010b on a GNU/Linux box. I'll see if my institution has a newer version of Matlab for download.

Comment: I've pastebinned my `zoom` replacement.  It works like zoom in that you turn it on with `simplezoom on` or `simplezoom xon` or `simplezoom yon`, and off with `simplezoom off`. It works with the original `WindowButtonDownFcn` strategy: you call `simplezoom('down')` from your window button-down callback to start a zoom provided your other conditions (modifier keys) are met.   http://pastebin.com/k0k8BNz2

Comment: Did you write all of that? It gives some interesting behavior. I'll have to experiment a bit more and see if I can make some changes. Currently, I simply call `simplezoom xon` in my main program, and associated a `WindowButtonDownFcn` callback function with the figure handle (`h`) via `set(h,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@mouse_callback)`. Within that callback function, `simplezoom('down')` is called if `ismember('control', get(gcbo,'currentModifier'))`. This gives only selection (x/y) zooming, even though I initially called `simplezoom` with `xon`. Also, the `shift` dependence of the zoom is ...

Comment: ... reversed (i.e., shift-click zooms in whereas click zooms out). Also, I notice that one can easily zoom out past the originally specified xlim, which in my case is meaningless because there is only data plotted for the original limits (so only zooming in and then zooming out not further than the original limits makes sense). An impressive zoom function you have written nonetheless.

Comment: Odd, I can't replicate the problem of `xon` not being respected.  The zooming out too far and/or reversal seems to be a "feature": for reasons I forget, the code *does* seem to be written to treat control + zoom as a special case: you'll want to change the switch statement right at the bottom, such that `case {'alt', 'normal'}` are handled identically in one case, removing the `case 'alt'` block.   And yeah, I've written a lot of stuff like that: I rely on a matlab feature, they change it, I curse a lot, I re-implement their stuff so I can continue to work in a backward-compatible way. Repeat.